# CUDA Link Error (Lib to Dll)

Tags: c++, c, dll, cuda

Im trying to create a framework to be able to use CUDA code in several game engine. To be able to communicate with all the wanted engines the frame consists of two main parts. A Lib and a DLL. The Lib contains all the functionality (CUDA and regular C++) and the DLL functions as a bridge to call functions from the Lib.

Now, everything was running oke untill I've included a .cu file. When I'm building I'm getting the following error:

```
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Add2And7 referenced in function "public: void __thiscall PerceptorHost::UpdatePerceptorHost(void)" (?UpdatePerceptorHost@PerceptorHost@@QAEXXZ)  D:\_Professional\DAE_Research\2_Projects\PWO_ePerceptor\Source\build\src\Native_ePerceptor_Dll\Native_ePerceptor_Lib.lib(PerceptorHost.obj) Native_ePerceptor_Dll
```

When I look at the buildlogs the Lib is building fine (Native_ePerceptor_Lib.lib). It's the DLL that fails.

Last but not least, the project has to be created using CMake (to be able to tackle different setups). Below you can find snippets of the .cu, Lib .cpp en the Dll .cpp. I looked across the interwebs to be able to find a solution but most of the solutions are regarding issues in one project and not regarding libraries. I'm pretty desperate at the moment so I hope some of you can point out what the issue, and hopefully, what a possible solution is.
One more thing, I'm pretty sure all the necessary libraries are being included (cudart, cuda).

**Kernel.cu**

```
#include <cuda\cuda_runtime.h>

__global__ void add(int a, int b, int *c) 
{
    *c += a + b;
    printf("%i + %i = %i \n", a, b, *c);
}

extern "C" void Add2And7(int *c)
{
    int *dev_c;

    //Allocate GPU memory
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_c, sizeof(int));

    add <<<1, 1>>>(2, 7, dev_c);

    //Copy GPU to CPU
    cudaMemcpy(c, dev_c, sizeof(int),
        cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    //printf("number is %u \n", &c);

    //Free allocated GPU memory
    cudaFree(dev_c);
}
```

**PerceptorHost.cpp**

```
//Forward declaration
extern "C" void Add2And7(int *c);

void PerceptorHost::UpdatePerceptorHost()
{
    if (!g_bIsBooted)
        return;

    if (!m_bTestKernel)
    {
        int output = 0;
        Add2And7(&output);
        printf("2 + 7 = %i \n", output);
        m_bTestKernel = true;
    }
}
```

**DLL.cpp**

```
extern "C" NATIVEDLL_API void __cdecl UpdatePerceptorHost()
{
    PERCEPTORHOST->UpdatePerceptorHost(); //Update the PerceptorHost and all it's managers
}
```

**CMAKE**

```
########################################################################
# Add all source files to variables
# CPU Source Files
FILE(GLOB SRCS *.cpp)
FILE(GLOB HDRS *.h )
FILE(GLOB CUDA_HDRS 
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/cuda/*.h)
FILE(GLOB CALIBRATION_FILES 
        RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Calibration/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Calibration/*.h)     
FILE(GLOB CORE_FILES 
        RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Core/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Core/*.h)   
FILE(GLOB DATAPROVIDER_FILES 
        RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Data/DataProvider/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Data/DataProvider/*.h)
FILE(GLOB RESOURCEMANAGER_FILES 
        RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Data/ResourceManager/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Data/ResourceManager/*.h)       
FILE(GLOB DEBUG_FILES 
        RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Debug/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Debug/*.h)  
FILE(GLOB EXCEPTION_FILES 
        RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Exceptions/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Exceptions/*.h)
FILE(GLOB HELPERS_FILES 
        RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Helpers/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Helpers/*.h)        
FILE(GLOB VIDEOWRITER_FILES 
        RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/VideoWriter/*.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/VideoWriter/*.h)
# GPU Source Files      
FILE(GLOB GPU_HELPERS_FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Helpers/*.cuh
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Helpers/*.cu)       

########################################################################
# Group all source files
SOURCE_GROUP("Calibration" FILES ${CALIBRATION_FILES})
SOURCE_GROUP("Core" FILES ${CORE_FILES})
SOURCE_GROUP("DataProvider" FILES ${DATAPROVIDER_FILES})
SOURCE_GROUP("ResourceManager" FILES ${RESOURCEMANAGER_FILES})
SOURCE_GROUP("Debug" FILES ${DEBUG_FILES})
SOURCE_GROUP("Exceptions" FILES ${EXCEPTION_FILES})
SOURCE_GROUP("Helpers" FILES ${HELPERS_FILES})
SOURCE_GROUP("VideoWriter" FILES ${VIDEOWRITER_FILES})

########################################################################
# Set this part as static lib
IF (D_ENABLE_LIBRARY_CUDA)
CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY(Native_ePerceptor_Lib
    ${CUDA_HDRS}
    ${CALIBRATION_FILES}
    ${CORE_FILES}
    ${DATAPROVIDER_FILES}
    ${RESOURCEMANAGER_FILES}
    ${DEBUG_FILES}
    ${EXCEPTION_FILES}
    ${HELPERS_FILES}
    ${VIDEOWRITER_FILES}
    ${SRCS}
    ${HDRS}
    ${GPU_HELPERS_FILES}
    )
ELSE()
    ADD_LIBRARY(Native_ePerceptor_Lib
    ${CUDA_HDRS}
    ${CALIBRATION_FILES}
    ${CORE_FILES}
    ${DATAPROVIDER_FILES}
    ${RESOURCEMANAGER_FILES}
    ${DEBUG_FILES}
    ${EXCEPTION_FILES}
    ${HELPERS_FILES}
    ${VIDEOWRITER_FILES}
    ${SRCS}
    ${HDRS}
    )
ENDIF()

########################################################################
# Add preprocessor defines
IF (D_ENABLE_LIBRARY_CUDA)
    CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8.11 FATAL_ERROR)
    FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
        ${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )
    set(CUDA_ENABLED ON)
    add_definitions(-DCUDA_ENABLED=1)
ENDIF (D_ENABLE_LIBRARY_CUDA)
IF (D_ENABLE_LIBRARY_OpenCV)
    add_definitions(-DOPENCV_ENABLED=1)
ENDIF (D_ENABLE_LIBRARY_OpenCV)
IF (D_ENABLE_LIBRARY_Glut)
    add_definitions(-DGLUT_ENABLED=1)
ENDIF (D_ENABLE_LIBRARY_Glut)

########################################################################
# Include Directories   
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Native_ePerceptor_Lib
    ${CUDA_LIBRARIES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Native_ePerceptor_Lib
    ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Native_ePerceptor_Lib
    ${Tobii_LIBRARIES})

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Native_ePerceptor_Lib
    ${Glut_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: I just tried a reduced version of your CMake file consisting just of `Kernel.cu` and `PerceptorHost.cpp` on Linux, GCC, CUDA 7 and CMake 3.0.2, and it compiled & linked successfully. Please convert your code into a minimal but compilable example (i.e. strip away as much as possible), that reproduces the error. Give more details on the tool versions you use. Consider upgrading CMake to the latest version.

Comment: Hi, thx for the tips. I've tried to convert everything into a smaller setup (still using the same setup - Lib -> Dll -> CMD for testing).
You can download it here: http://we.tl/DITxuAm3Dd.
It would be great if you can take a look.

My tools are: Windows 8.1, CMakeGUI 3.2.2, NVCC, CUDA 7.0

Comment: Your code is still way too much, aside from that I cannot build it on Linux since you are using Windows specific includes etc. But why do you have defined `void Add2And7(int *c)` as a `__device__` function? you are calling it from the host, so it must NOT be decorated as `__device__`.

Comment: Yes indeed, the __device__ define is not correct. I guess I need to expose it as an extern function? It must indeed be called from the host using the "Boot" function, which is callable from the DLL.
Problem with cutting down more code is that I loose the structure of the project, what is the cause of the issue as far as I can think off. Because I can successfully build all the samples included with CUDA.

Comment: You can use `extern "C"` (as you did in the example in the your post), but a plain C++ function should work as well.

Comment: Oke thank you. I changed two thing in the project i've shared. I've changed the 'Build Customization' to use CUDA 7.0(.targets, .props), and for the TestKernel.cu I've changed it's type to CUDA C/C++ in the Class Property Page. So, my next question would be, is it possible to set these settings from CMake and how? :) I'm pretty new at CMake.

Comment: does it link correctly now? regarding your other questions: please post a new SO question, however, usually this settings should be already correct through CMake.

Comment: I'll post a new question :) Thank you!
It indeed links correctly now. Everything builds and runs fine by changing these two settings and the smaller project.
If I find the CMake solution I'll post it here too for other users.

Comment: Hmmmm... I tried to do the two new steps manually in my older project (just added the structure to the Lib part of the project) and I'm getting the following error message from CUDA 7.0.targets:

Err 1 error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "SourceLib.dir\Debug\C:\Users\Matthieu\Desktop\Project\src\SourceLib\Helpers\". The given path's format is not supported. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 7.0.targets 412 9 SourceLib

Comment: I've searched for a solution but I can't find any. Everyone is talking about this part "SourceLib.dir\Debug\C:\Users.......", but I don't find an useful solution.

If I don't set the .targets file it won't build. I'll get the older error. Any help?

Comment: This is not a valid directory:  "SourceLib.dir\Debug\C:\Users......."   You have entered a project setting (path)  incorrectly.  If you have solved the problem in this question, please post an answer so we can get it off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

Oke, I was able to resolve the issue without the previous mentioned solution (changing Build Customization + setting file to CUDA C/C++)

The problem was that indeed the symbols of my header file that defined my CUDA function was not being exported. So with my project structure (LIB -> DLL -> CMD) this was an issue. I was able to using it in a LIB -> CMD structure. I resolved the issue by defining the header function as follow:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void Add2And7(int *);
```

instead of:

```
extern "C" void Add2And7(int *);
```

I don't know if there is anything wrong with doing this (it works :))?
If I check out MSDN I think it fine using the export keyword.

Using _declspec(dllexport)

> The dllexport and dllimport storage-class attributes are
>   Microsoft-specific extensions to the C and C++ languages. You can use
>   them to export and import functions, data, and objects to or from a
>   DLL.

Comment: Since you didn't specify `STATIC`, the `CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY` is creating a shared (dll) project, that's why you need `_declspec(dllexport)` for windows dll.