# CUDA error MSB3191

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I tried to do the two new steps manually in my older project ([CUDA Link Error (Lib to Dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30320349/cuda-link-error-lib-to-dll?noredirect=1#comment48746468_30320349)) to get my CUDA kernel running (just added the structure to the Lib part of the project). The steps are:

**1:** Project's 'Build Customization' to use CUDA 7.0(.targets, .props)

**2:** TestKernel.cu I've changed it's type to CUDA C/C++ in the Class Property Page.

Now I'm getting the following error message from CUDA 7.0.targets:

> Error    1   error MSB3191: Unable to create directory
>   "SourceLib.dir\Debug\C:\Users\Matthieu\Desktop\Project\src\SourceLib\Helpers\".
>   The given path's format is not supported. C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
>   7.0.targets   412 9   SourceLib

I've searched for a solution but I can't find any. Everyone is talking about this part "**SourceLib.dir\Debug**\C:\Users.......", which obviously looks wrong, but I can't find the setting in Visual Studio or CMake. Where can I adjust this?

It's similar to this question ([CUDA 6.5: error MSB3191 Unable to create directory and LNK2001 Unresolved External symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719933/cuda-6-5-error-msb3191-unable-to-create-directory-and-lnk2001-unresolved-extern)), but I can't fix it by copying the .cu file.

If I don't set the .targets file it won't build. I'll get the older error. Any help? 
And alternative for getting the setup running using Cmake is also welcome :)
Thx!

Comment: I think a semicolon (`;`) is missing after **Debug\.**

Answer (score 2):

The issue was that the CMake file was filling "SourceLib.dir\Debug" into the Intermediate Directory property (Project Properties -> General). Deleting it resolved the issue with the CUDA 7.0 target

Comment: You should see my updated answer in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719933/cuda-6-5-error-msb3191-unable-to-create-directory-and-lnk2001-unresolved-extern